# Import external resource with Freemarker or Velocity in Liferay

Tags: liferay-6, freemarker, liferay-velocity

I want to import an external resource from the filesystem to a Webcontent Template in Liferay (6.1). Can this be done with an include instruction (#include) from Freemarker or Velocity ?

Answer (score 0):

By Velocity - No, the security rule allowed only import (include) templates from the Template-Root directory, see Velocity documentation: https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#include

By Freemarker - Yes, see the docu: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_import.html